# Как реализовать удаление поля таблиц в форме

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jpa

Вот моя форма

```
<form " action="/delete/?userId=${users.userId}" method="POST" target="_blank">
<input type="submit" class="update_Delete" value="DELETE"  onclick="javascript:deleteUser(${users.userId})"/>                              </form>
```

А Контроллере так:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView deleteUser(@PathVariable("userId") Integer userId, Users users ) { 

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("usersList");
    try {
        usersDAOService.delUser(userId);
        String delMessage = "User by id number is " + usersDAOService.getUsersById(users.getUserId()) + " was succesfully removed";
        modelAndView.addObject("message", delMessage);
        return modelAndView;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("This user is does not deleted, please try later!");
        return new ModelAndView("usersList");
    }
}
```

Что здесь неправильно?

Объясните пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо всем за ответ

Comment: HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

type Status report

message Request method 'POST' not supported

description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.

Comment: Ошибка выйдет вот так

Comment: method = RequestMethod.POST должно быть. Вообще в HTTP предусмотрен метод DELETE, но при отправке формы повсеместно используется POST (другой вариант GET). DELETE и другие "редкие" методы HTTP используется в RESTful, например.

Comment: зачем делать онклик на удаления если уже стоит екшн?

Comment: Может там более сложная обработка, чем просто отправка формы. Например надо к `/delete` добавить параметр, чтобы было `/delete?userId=123`. Так же вариант, что вместо формы действительно пытается выполнить DELETE в RESTful стиле.

Comment: Ну Сергей если использую по вашему  /delete?userId=123, здесь по моему, если я прав вы использовали методом GET? А мне сказали что метод GET для чтения или извлечения данных из базы, а  POST что бы для  изменение или удаление данных по Id или что то другое. А контроллере то же идет метод POST.

Comment: Здесь onclick я использую для подтверждения (через java script) и без этого тоже так.

Comment: Да какой POST в контроллере, если там написано `@RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)`? `DELETE`!!!

Comment: А значит мне там изменить их оба на GET и на экшене как вы предлагали? Сейчас попробую..

Comment: Заменить в контроллере что-бы было `method = RequestMethod.POST` и всё. Что вы к этому GET привязались? Он даже в скобках упомянут был, как бы между прочим. (Хотя и с GET должно сработать). Тогда либо всё заработает, либо нет, но ошибки `HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST'` уже точно не будет.

Comment: Ну я беспокою вас еще раз, сейчас я сделал с методом GET <form action="/delete/?userId=${users.userId} method="GET" >.. и получаю ошибку что здесь я по моему неправильно ввел адрес:         HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: Ну можете объяснить что в моем методе  все правильно?

Comment: Не известно осталось как userId попадает в запрос. В этом аспекте тоже всё должно совпадать как и методы. С начала у вас было  `@RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{userId}", ...` Т.е. сервер ждёт запрос на адрес http://server:port/app/delete/123. Но `<form action="/delete/" ...`. Естественно предположить, что скрипт добавляет 123 к строке запроса. Нет? Тогда либо сделать так `<form action="/delete/${users.userId}" ...`, либо в скрипте всё-таки сделать такую добавку. А может какой-то другой механизм. никто не видел вашего скрипта. Теперь всё от него зависит.

Comment: Это  так:                                                                                         <script language="JavaScript">        
        function deleteUser(userid) {
            if (confirm('Do you want delete this user')) {
                var url = '/delete' + userid;
                window.location.href = url;
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }

    </script>

Comment: должно быть как минимум `var url = '/delete/' + userid;` у вас нет `/` между `delete` и `userId`. А вообще лучше сделать `<form action="/delete/${users.userId}" ...` и `function deleteUser(userid) { if (! confirm('Do you want delete this user')) return false; }`